# Prevent dangerouslySetInnerHTML from inheriting css in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I don't want to mix my application with the css that is included in the html element that i'm receiving.

Is there a way to prevent dangerouslySetInnerHTML from inheriting style from the current page?

```html
return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: template }}></div>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could display the content in an iframe, which would have its own CSS.

Not the solution you're asking for, but you could instead add a class to your div and override the styles that you don't want to impact your HTML content. This might be reasonable if you don't have many styles to override.

Comment: Good response. Unless it's a very simple page and you know exactly what you're getting from the `innerHTML`, (which, based on the word "dangerous" I wouldn't assume), the iframe is probably the safest bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
return (
    <div 
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: template }} 
        style={{all : "initial"}}>
    </div>
)
```

This style specifies that all the element's properties should be changed to their initial values.

You can read more about this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all